# How to Index and Search multiple terms and phrases with Lucene

Tags: search, lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.NET to index the contents of a set of documents.  My index contains several fields, but I'm mainly concerned with querying the "contents" field.  I'm trying to figure out the best way of indexing, as well as creating the query, to meet the requirements.

Here are the current requirements:

- Able to search multiple keywords, such as "planes trains automobiles" (minus the quotes).  This should give me all documents that contain ANY of the terms, but the documents that contain all three should be at the top
- Able to search for phrases, such as "planes, trains, and automobiles" (with quotes) which would only match if they were together in that order.
- As for stop words, I would be ok with either ignoring them altogether, or including them.
- As for punctuation or special characters, same deal.  I can either ignore them completely, or include them.
- The last two just need to be consistent, not necessarily with each other, but with how the indexer and searcher handles them.  So I just don't want to have a case where the user searches for "planes and trains" but it doesn't match a document that does contain that phrase, because the indexer took out the "and" but the searcher is trying to search for that particular phrase.

Some of the documents are large, so I think we don't want to do Field.Store.Yes, right?  Unless we have to for what we need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirements you've listed should be handled just fine by using lucene's standard analyzer and queryparser.  Make sure to use the same analyzer in the IndexWriter and the QueryParser.  Stop words are eliminated.  Punctuation is generally ignored, though the rules are a bit more involved that just ignoring *every* punctuation character (see [UAX #29, section 4](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries), if you are interested in the details)

If you try running the [Lucene demo](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/demo/overview-summary.html#Indexing_Files), you should find it works just about as you've specified here.

As far as storing the field, you have it right, yes.  Store the field if you need to retrieve it from the index.  Large fields that you don't need to retrieve do not need to be stored.